# Change the MySQL driver used by Joomla

Tags: mysql, joomla

When I was installing Joomla, **mysqli** was the default option, so I installed with mysqli driver.

But the database of my client is mysqli. So when i migrate my local site to the host, i get this error:

> Database connection error (1): The MySQL adapter 'mysqli' is not available.

Can someone know how I change/go back to 'mysql' driver? Because I configured all my Joomla sites in localhost with the 'mysqli' driver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open configuration.php and change this:

```
public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
```

to this

```
public $dbtype = 'mysql';
```

Comment: @odyodyodys - what do you mean "why"? It can't be changed in the global configuration in the joomla backend as whenever the OP tries to access the website, they get the database connection error, and thus it needs to be done manually

Comment: @RogerDahl MySQL is obsolete and removed in PHP 7. Mysqli and PDO MySQL are the options to migrated.