# Database connection error (1): The MySQL adapter 'mysqli' is not available

Tags: joomla

I changed my `upload_max_filesize` in php.ini from 2M to 5M.
I get this error

```
Database connection error (1): The MySQL adapter 'mysqli' is not available.
```

Changes back to the original state return.
but had no effect.
I'm using wampS.
help me
how do I fix it? and how I change "upload_max_filesize" that don't occure problem???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the MySQL driver used by Joomla](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703509/change-the-mysql-driver-used-by-joomla)

Comment: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703509/change-the-mysql-driver-used-by-joomla

Answer (score 2):

Possible problem in the driver database.
Try to replace `$dbtype = 'mysqli'` on `$dbtype = 'mysql'` in the file configuration.php